# Save Dragable sitemap with jquery to database

Tags: jquery, database, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a question, I found a great script that I want to use for my website but I don't know how to save it to my database, the link [here](http://boagworld.com/technology/creating-a-draggable-sitemap-with-jquery/), could someone point me to the right direction?
Thanks

Take a look at the [demo](http://boagworld.com/demos/sitemap/). I want to be able to sort the list and then save it to my database.

There is a function history but I just can't figure it out

```
`var sitemapHistory = {
   stack: new Array(),
   temp: null,
   //takes an element and saves it's position in the sitemap.
   //note: doesn't commit the save until commit() is called!
   //this is because we might decide to cancel the move
   saveState: function(item) {
      sitemapHistory.temp = { item: $(item), itemParent: $(item).parent(), itemAfter:  
      $(item).prev() };
   },
   commit: function() {
   if (sitemapHistory.temp != null) sitemapHistory.stack.push(sitemapHistory.temp);
   },
   //restores the state of the last moved item.
   restoreState: function() {
   var h = sitemapHistory.stack.pop();
   if (h == null) return;
   if (h.itemAfter.length > 0) {
      h.itemAfter.after(h.item);
   }
   else {
      h.itemParent.prepend(h.item);
   }
   //checks the classes on the lists
   $('#sitemap li.sm2_liOpen').not(':has(li)').removeClass('sm2_liOpen');
   $('#sitemap li:has(ul li):not(.sm2_liClosed)').addClass('sm2_liOpen');
   }
}
`
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a sitemap in HTML yourself. It has to look like the example on the page: `<ul id=”sitemap”> <li> <dl> <dt><a href=”#”>expand/collapse</a> ...`

Then you include the script from the page and run it.

Not sure what all this has to do with your database.

Comment: take a look at the demo: http://boagworld.com/demos/sitemap/ i want to be able to sort the list and then save it to my database

Comment: I saw the demo. You could use $('#sitemap').html() to get get map and save the string to your database with an [ajax query](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to add a linkID and a parentID to each line element. Then when you save the changes, make the updates to your table on the back end.  That would cover the parent / child relationships. As for the sorting order, I'm still thinking about that.

A valuable resource is the jQuery Sortable document : http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/